# Why does making an array pointer work better than an array in this situation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have two ways of creating an array of N+1 elements, all filled with zeroes.

```
long int *a=new long int[N+1]();
```

vs.

```
long int a[N+1] = {0};
```

why does the first approach work better with larger inputs while the second one usually results in segmentation fault?

Comment: Funny you should ask this question on StackOverflow.

Comment: The second approach creates the array in stack (rather than in heap), and stack size is usually limited by a few megabytes.